# Hide content of first page using @page

Tags: css, printing, pug

I'm using pug to create a template for contracts. In this contract I'll show some content in the header on the first page, and other content on the rest of the pages. I'm able to show an image on just the first page, but I cannot for the life of me get it to hide the content on the first page, that are only supposed to be shown on the other pages.

styling:

```
@page :first { 
        .student { display: none !important; }
        .logo { display: block; }
     }
     @page {
        .logo { display: none;}
        .student {display: block; }
     }
```

pug-markup:

```
body
   header
      table(style='width:100%', border='0')
         tr
            //Logo on first page
            td
               div.logo 
                  img(src=user.brand.logo)
            // Table student-info on other pages
            td#table-wrapper.student
               table(style='width:100%', border='1')#desc
                  tr 
                     td.logo 
                        table(style='width: 400%', border='0')
                           tr
                              td(class='label') Elev
                           tr
                              td(class='normal') some data
                  tr
                     td 
                        table(style='width: 100%', border='0')
                           tr
                              td(class='label') Personnr
                           tr
                              td(class='normal') some data
            // Header - always show
            td(class='right-align')
               h2(class='no-margin') Utbildningskontrakt
               h6 väldigt liten text här
               h6 liten text här med
```

Have tried changing the @page to @page :not(:first), which doesn't work either.

Comment: Should it be `@page:first` without a space?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The @page rule can only contain page properties and margin at-rules.

you can try to use [Named pages](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#using-named-pages).